# Nuget Restore in MS Build Step

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, tfsbuild, msbuild-task, nuget-package-restore

In my asp.net web application, i have solution with 5 projects and nuget.org. In TFS Build Definition,

1) While building the whole solution in **Visual Studio Build Task**

```
         Nuget packages getting restored.
```

2) While trying to generate executable files for individual projects in **MS Build Task**

If I select Restore Nuget packages, It's not finding nuget packages and step getting failed with message - "Process 'NuGet.exe' exited with code '1'."

I have tried many references online and none worked. Any suggestions on how to solve this?
Do i need to make any changes in the nuget.config file to support restoring
 packages to individual projects.

Comment: Hi Gauty, `If i select Restore Nuget packages` did this  mean you have selected the  **Restore NuGet Packages** option  in Advanced  of the MSBuild Task configuration?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT Yes, I have selected the option in Advanced Dropdown. My build definition steps in order: 1) Nuget Installer, 2) Visual Studio Build task for whole solution, 3) Four MS Build Tasks to generate publish files for individual projects. The visual studio build task is able to restore the nuget packages, but not the same in the case of MS build tasks, where it uses individual projects.

Comment: First uncheck the  "Restore Nuget pacakges" option  in Advanced dropdown, since  you have used Nuget installer  task already.  What's the result if  you move  Visual Studio Build task only use MS build tasks?

Comment: When i uncheck the "Restore Nuget pacakges" in MSBuild task to generate publish files for an individual project, the build is getting succeeded. But, when i post those files to server, the events are not getting logged in to the database. I have figured out the bin files created in visual studio build and MS build are of different size. When i uncheck "Restore Nuget pacakges" in visualstudioBuild task, it's creating bin files similar to MSBuild. Hence, i have noticed that the package restore is not happening in the MSBuild Task and causing the issue

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT,  I have just restored packages from nuget.org with nuget installer step. But, we have custom packages too. we used to restore the custom packages by updating a URI in package manager console. But, the build server could not find those custom packages when an TFS build is triggered. I have browsed online on how to update custom packages on build machine. I have seen that we can update package sources in Nuget.Config file, or update using powershell script in build definition. Could you please suggest me, what's the recommended way to update custom packages on a build machine

Answer (score 2):

Do not directly select **Restore Nuget pacakges** in MS build task configuration. This option is **deprecated**. To restore NuGet packages, add a NuGet Installer step before the build.

> (**Important**) This option is deprecated. Make sure to clear this
>   checkbox and instead use the [NuGet Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/package/nuget) build step.
>
> *Source Link: [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/build/msbuild)*

Besides, you could also build single project not the entire solution in Visual Studio Build task. Just select the project (`.*proj`) files instead of `.sln` file.
Unless you are building a customized MSBuild project file, then we recommend you use the MSBuild step instead of the Visual Studio Build step.

You could also try to build single project using Visual Studio Build task, see if the issue is still exists.

Comment: I have tried visualStudioBuild task for .*proj file instead of MS Build task. Still if i check the option "Restore Nuget Packages", it's getting failed. SInce, the nuget can be found under solution and not in this individual project, it's unable to find the packages to restore. Do i need to make any changes in nuget.org or nuget.targets to utilize nuget in individual projects rather than just solution.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, downgraded to 4.4.1. it helped

Comment: 4.4.1?  do you mean nuget version under Nuget Installer Task(Advanced).