# project.assets.json not found with msbuild

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, msbuild

I have an ASP.NET Core application that i wish to build on a jenkins machine with MSBuild 15.

When i try to build i get the following error:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.502\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(198,
>   5): error NETSDK1004: Assets file 'C:\sync\Src\Util\myUtil\ob
>   j\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file

I understand that i need to do nuget restore somehow, but i failed to make it work.

My build process:
Running a batch filed with the following command:

```
call "%VS150COMNTOOLS%VsDevCmd.bat"
MSBuild DailyBuild.proj /t:DailyBuild /p:VersionNumber=%2 /l:FileLogger,Microsoft.Build.Engine;logfile=Build.log
```

The DailyBuild.proj file look like this:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SourcesPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\..\</SourcesPath>
    <CSCleanProperties>BuildType=Clean;Configuration=Release;IsFormalBuild=true</CSCleanProperties>
    <CSBuildProperties>BuildType=ReBuild;Configuration=Release;PauseBuildOnError=false;PublishWebSites=true;VersionName=myProd-$(VersionNumber)</CSBuildProperties>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="DailyBuildWithClean">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Make.proj" Targets="Clean" Properties="$(CSCleanProperties)"/>
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Make.proj" Properties="$(CSCleanProperties)"/>
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Make.proj" Targets="FormalBuild" Properties="$(CSBuildProperties)"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="DailyBuild">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Make.proj" Targets="SW;PreparePackFolder" Properties="$(CSBuildProperties)"/>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

The Make.proj is a proj file containing definitions for many applications to be built, one of them is my ASP.NET Core app.

How do i fix this problem? thank you.

SOLUTION EDIT:
Thanks to solution by Martin Ullrich:

Added in the DailyBuild.proj the target Restore, also added in the Make.proj a target called restore as suggested 
(IE:

```
<Target Name="Restore">
  <MSBuild Projects="$(SourcesPath)\my.sln" Targets="Restore" />
</Target>
```

)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assets file project.assets.json not found. Run a NuGet package restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440223/assets-file-project-assets-json-not-found-run-a-nuget-package-restore)

Comment: I have seen this but it doesnt help me. Im trying to build with MSBuild (specifically with a build machine) not with dotnet so dotnet restore is not helping me. Unless you have something more to add because this answer is not helping me

Comment: If you are going to use .net core you have to follow SDK rules. I would recommend you to get rid off .proj files and msbuild operation and use dotnet CLI and Cake as a build tool.

Comment: I can not find the `restore` command. Did I miss something?

Comment: i didnt include the restore command because whichever way i tried it didnt work (msbuild -t:restore or msbuild /t:restore always lead to restore target not found)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add `-r` (`-restore`/`/Restore`) to your MSBuild command to trigger a restore before the main build.

The restore parameter will build the `Restore` target, clear internal caches and then run the rest of the build as specified.

Since you build a custom MSBuild project, you then need to add a `Restore` target to it:

```
<Target Name="Restore">
  <MSBuild Projects="$(SourcesPath)\my.sln" Targets="Restore" />
</Target>
```

(or alternatively add another `Restore` target on the make.proj file and forward it from there to the solution or individual projects that you need to be restored)

Comment: Thank you this is what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Be careful using Restore Nuget packages directly in MS build task configuration. 
This option is deprecated, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48508960/nuget-restore-in-ms-build-step) for Azure DevOps.  (However, I am not sure how context-dependent that is.)

> **(Important)** This option is deprecated. Make sure to clear this checkbox and instead use the [NuGet Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/package/nuget) build step.
>
> Source Link: [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/build/msbuild)

However, I already used that step (in TFS), so this obviously would not fix it for me.

I tried removing the packages-folder in Source Control Explorer as mentioned [here](http://robertgreiner.com/2013/09/team-foundation-service-build-error-nuget/), but that did not fix it either.

Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48556514/project-assets-json-not-found-tfs-build-server-no-internet), I upgraded the TFS NuGet Installer build step to use Nuget 4.0 (in "Advanced" options), and that did fix it.  (Maybe in combination with the removal of the packages-folder?)

Answer (score -5):

Simply rebuild your project in another location(directory/folder ) and run your solution it works 100%.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to address any of the details in the question.